# using clojure symbol function to make indirect function call

Tags: clojure

I'm expecting below that I should be able to call my function squared indirectly via the symbol function, but its not working. What am I doing wrong here:

```
user=> (defn squared [x] (* x x))
#'user/squared
user=> (squared 2)
4
user=> ((symbol "squared") 2)
nil
user=> ((symbol "user" "squared") 2)
nil
user=>
```

Comment: The basic issue with the code (hopefully addressed by my answer) aside, I'm a bit curious about the problem you're solving, if you'd be willing to go into more detail...?

Comment: its a bit of a rabbit hole and I'm a complete novice...but basically I ran into "Can't take value of a macro" because I'm doing something like `(a :b c & d)` where both a and c are macros. I was hoping if I switch that to `(a :b :c & d)` and then convert :c to a symbol it will work. I have a feeling this is completely wrong actually, but since my little idea of `((symbol "squared") 2)` didn't work I figured I'd ask how that works....

Comment: If you get this sort of error with an `(a :b c & d)` form, then most likely `a` produces an expansion which includes `c` verbatim in non-operator position. If you only want to include the name of the `c` macro in the expansion (and the actual thing you pass to `a` is the symbolic name of the macro `c`), then you could just add a quote to the expansion, so that you return `'c` rather than `c` in the appropriate place. If you actually want to call the `c` macro, you need to make sure that it ends up being inserted in the operator position in the expansion produced by `a`.

Comment: actually what I really want to do, is write some macro that takes `(defmacro [x] ...)` where I know that x is a form like `(f a b c)` and I want to transform it to `(fn [n] (f n a b c))`. But I'm not sure if this is possible or how to even begin to go about it if it is. I feel like I should open a new question if you want to take a stab at it.

Comment: `(defmacro transform [[f & args]] (fn [n#] (~f n# ~@args)))` should work.

Comment: No worries about the new question... I mean I guess it would be more convenient if it turns out more details are needed, but I think the above should work...?

Comment: let me play with it a bit...but since I'm a noob it might take me a while, thanks!

Comment: Just noticed: there should be a backtick in front of `(fn [n#] (~f n# ~@args))` in the definition of `transform` above. (Is it possible to include one in an SO comment?)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The symbol itself does not hold your function, the Var it names does.

This says "take the contents (`@` = `deref`) of the Var (`resolve`) named by the symbol (`symbol`) whose name is `"squared"` and apply it (as a function) to the argument `2`:

```
(@(resolve (symbol "squared")) 2)
```

This says "take the Var named by the symbol etc.":

```
((resolve (symbol "squared")) 2)
```

Both will work, since Vars, when asked to act as a function, defer to the functions stored in them. (If you try to use a Var as a function when it is not bound to a function, an error will result.)

This says "take the symbol named `"squared"` and apply it as a function to the argument `2`" -- note that the symbol itself is used as the function:

```
((symbol "squared") 2)
```

Now symbols can be used as functions (they implement the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface), but the way they act when used in this way is that they look themselves up in their argument, i.e. treat their argument as a map and perform a lookup inside it:

```
('foo {'foo 2})
; is equivalent to
(get {'foo 2} 'foo)
```

If the argument passed to a symbol is not something it makes sense to do lookups in, `nil` is returned.

Comment: (@(resolve (symbol "squared")) 2) does not work.....this is what it outputs - [#<core$_STAR_ clojure.core$_STAR_@1fdac27> 4 4]

Comment: It works for me -- I just pasted the definition of `squared` into a REPL followed by `(@(resolve (symbol "squared")) 2)` (copied from your comment) and got `4` as the response: http://pastie.org/2508000 Could you please double check that you are using the same definition of `squared` etc.?