# What's the difference between read-string and load-string in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have the following form:

`((read-string "+") 2 3)`

It returns `3`

I have two questions about this:

1) Why does the form above return `3` instead of `nil` or throwing an exception or anything else? How exactly is this form resolving?
2) What is returned from `read-string` in this case? And how is it different from if I had used `load-string`?

Comment: It has actually little to do with `read-string`. Try `('foo 2 3)` and you'll get the same result.

Comment: or, what is more demonstrative: `('+ {'+ 10} 11)` , `('+ {'- 10} 11}`

Comment: Here is a directly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219305/what-happens-when-i-pass-arguments-to-a-clojure-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1. Basically passing arguments to symbols cause them to look up themselves in the first arg, the second arg would be the default value, hence getting 3 as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are actually doing is using a symbol as a function and passing arguments to it. You can read a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7355158/157216) that covers this in more detail. From the answer:

> Now symbols can be used as functions (they implement the
>   clojure.lang.IFn interface), but the way they act when used in this
>   way is that they look themselves up in their argument, i.e. treat
>   their argument as a map and perform a lookup inside it

As stated in @akond's answer, `read-string` returns a symbol and `load-string` evaluates that too. You could trigger the same behavior by passing any other symbol:

```
((symbol 'hi) 2 3)
;; 3
('foo 2 3)
;; 3
('foo '{foo 2} 3)
;; 2
('foo 2)
;; nil since there is no default value provided
```

If you are curious you can have a look at [Symbol implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L132) in Clojure source code.

Answer (score 4):

`(read-string "+")` returns a symbol `+` that could be resolved or evaluated to get an actual value, i.e. `+` function.

`load-string` returns the result of the expression.

In other words `load-string` equals to `(eval (read-string "+"))`

You don't get nil or an exception because the language does evaluation for you.

1. Compiler resolves symbol `+` in order to evaluate the expression.
2. `+` symbol is resolved to #'clojure.core/+ according to current namespace aliases, because core aliases are always available.

   ```
   (class (read-string "+"))
   ; => clojure.lang.Symbol
   (class (resolve (read-string "+")))
   ; => clojure.lang.Var
   (class (deref (resolve (read-string "+"))))
   ; => clojure.core$_PLUS_`
   ```